# How does tomcat resolve resources?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I develop web application.

Spring+Hibernate on Tomcat servlet container.

Today on another PC I deploy application and see that css doesn't  load.

in jsp I use relative paths for this(example)

```
<link href="/resources/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Respective request which browser sends:

```
http://localhost:8080/resources/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css
```

and this request  returns 404 http error.

---

for another jsp:

```
<link href="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

browser sends:

```
http://localhost:8080/terminal-company/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Thus you can see that from first jsp project name doesn't add to the URL

Why? and how to fix it?  request me detail which I should to add to relevant answer.

### project structure:

[image]

spring related part of web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you show us the project folder structure?

Comment: `href="/resources/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css"` That is not a relative resource, it starts with `/`...

Comment: did you make the changes in your web.xml, as you are using spring

Comment: Could you please show web.xml

Comment: @Naveen topic updated

Comment: @gstackoverflow you have forgot to add servlet mapping for your css files

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

This will work i guess cause i also had same issues

Comment: @Naveen please post the answer I want to know it is good practise or not.

Comment: @gstackoverflow this is the practice which i follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to be able to use absolute paths, without caring (and knowing) about the context path of the webapp (`/terminal-company` in your second example), then use [the JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:url>` tag to generate all your URLs:

```
<link href="<c:url value='/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css'/>" rel="stylesheet">
```

The second example will send a request to `/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css`, and not to `/terminal-company/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css`, unless there is a `<base>` tag in the generated HTML page.

EDIT: your original question didn't say you were using spring, and mapped / to the dispatcher servlet. Spring is thus in charge of service resources. [The documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources) explains how to configure it. But that doesn't change anything to the above answer: to be independant of the context path, use c:url.

Comment: my goal to be independent on context path. What is best practice for this?

Comment: **unless there is a <base> tag in the generated HTML page.** where can I find it?

Comment: The best practice is to use the c:url tag, as explained in my answer. To find the base tag, open the generated html page in any editor, and search for `<base`

Answer (score 0):

you have forgot to add servlet mapping in web.xml for your css files.

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This applies same for all your js, png.

This will work i guess cause i also had same issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same behaviour running on localhost. Just add the default servlet which will then serve static resources like css, js, images and so on.
The mapping must be placed before your "/" urlpattern because "/" will match "/js".

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```